# What is this word on top of my character vector in R and how do I get rid of it

Tags: r

I want to isolate a value in the summary of a data frame, so I wrote:

```
> summary(pf$mobile_likes > 0)[2]
  FALSE 
"35056"
```

The response to my command is a character vector, and I can convert it to an integer

```
> typeof(summary(pf$mobile_likes > 0)[2])
[1] "character"
> strtoi(summary(pf$mobile_likes > 0)[2])
[1] 35056
```

Still, I don't understand why that `FALSE` header shows up on top.  What is it, and how can I isolate my character vector from it?

Comment: It's a table name.  Try wrapping the call in `unname`

Comment: You're right, thanks.  Feel free to submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your summary is a vector, and what you're seeing there is an element name.

You can wrap the call in `unname` to get rid of the names.

```
> x <- 1:5
> (summ <- summary(x > 2)[2:3])
# FALSE  TRUE 
#   "2"   "3" 
> names(summ)
# [1] "FALSE" "TRUE" 
> unname(summ)
# [1] "2" "3"
```